# How to decide group assignments in Dirichlet process clustering

Tags: process, cluster-analysis, probability, distribution, dirichlet

As in the Dirichlet clustering, the dirichlet process can be represented by the following:

- Chinese Restaurant Process
- Stick Breaking Process
- Poly Urn Model

For instance, if we consider `Chinese Restaurant Process` the process is as follows:

- Initially the restaurant is empty
- The first person to enter (Alice) sits down at a table (selects a
  group).
- The second person to enter (Bob) sits down at a table.
- Which table does he sit at?
- He sits down at a ***new table*** with probability `α/(1+α)`
- He sits with at ***existing table*** with Alice (mean he'll join existing group)
  with probability `1/(1+α)`
- The (n+1)-st person sits down at a new table with probability
  `α/(n+α)α/(n+α)`, and at table k with probability `nk/(n+α)nk/(n+α)`,
  where `nk` is the number of people currently sitting at table k.

The question is:

Initially, the first person will join, say G1 (i.e. group 1),
Now the second person will join

```
new group      = G2 with probability α/(1+α) = P(N)  
existing group = G1 with probability 1/(1+α) = P(E)
```

Now if I calculate the probabilities for *new entry*, I'll have values for both i.e. `P(N)` and `P(E)`. Then,

- *How will I decide that new entry will join which group **G1** or **G2***?
- *Would it be decided on basis of values of both probabilities*?

As,

```
If (P(N) > P(E))  
then  
   _new entry_ will join G2    
AND  
If (P(E) > P(N))  
then
_new entry_ will join G1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the CRP representation,

- customer 1 sits at table 1
- customer i, sits at pre-occupied table k with p_k and at a new table with p_new where

[image]
[image]

Note that the sum of the probabilities is equal to 1. To find the table assignment, all you have to do is toss a coin and select the relevant table.

For example for customer i, assume you have the following probability vector

[image]

which means the probability of sitting at table 1 is 0.2, table 2 is 0.4, table 3 is 0.3, and a new table is 0.1. By constructing the cumulative probability vector and drawing a random number, you can sample the table. Let's say the random number 0.81, therefore your customer sits at table 3.