# dirichlet process group selection

Tags: process, cluster-analysis, probability, distribution, dirichlet

I understand the dirichlet process group selection as explained here: [How to decide group assignments in Dirichlet process clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859521/how-to-decide-group-assignments-in-dirichlet-process-clustering)

But I don't understand why the DP group selection algorithm doesn't use a new item's features to determine the best group membership. How will a DP find the distinct groups if it doesn't use the members' features to guide group membership?

Answer (score 0):

The "generative model" is *not* a program to label new items.

It's a hypothetical program to *generate* 'fake' data. If you are generating data, you have to first choose the group, then generate the attributes. There is are no "existing" features that you could use.

To label observed data, you have to infer the parameters that are most likely to have generated this new data if it had been randomly generated.

Answer (score 0):

After putting the items into random clusters initially, the training phase moves items one at a time to the cluster that they are closest to or puts them in a new cluster if there isn't a close fit to an existing cluster. The training phase is run until convergence (there are no movements of items to different clusters).